# Defining semaphores from a pseudocode

Tags: c, semaphore

This is a follow of my previous question: [Fork(); method in C: determine order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029344/fork-method-in-c-determine-order)

I now want to learn how to define the semaphores from this pseudocode, including structures and operations.
I only find too complex examples of semaphores definitions, so I don't get them at all.

The pseudocode from the previous post:

```
Th1 { display "Hello 1" }
Th2 { display "Hello 2" }
Th3 { display "Hello 3" }

main() {
    Fork(Th1);Fork(Th2);Fork(Th3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether you are trying to define your own semaphore implementation or you'd like to use the [POSIX](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) implementation.

Using POSIX semaphores, you should first declare a global semaphore to be used by your different threads (in your case, they seem to be different processes) as follows:

```
sem_t name_of_your_semaphore;
```

After that, you need to initialize your semaphore using sem_init:

```
sem_init(&name_of_your_semaphore, pshared, initial_value);
```

Where pshared and initial_value are both int. As you can see from the the sem_init [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init) if pshared is 0, the semaphore can be shared across threads within a single process. If pshared is not 0, it can be shared across multiple processes. Since you are using the fork system call in your program, you are actually creating different processes so you should use a non-zero pshared value.
initial_value is the initial value of your semaphore. If you initialize it to 1, you call it a binary semaphore and it can be used to provide mutual exclusion. If you initialize it to a value greater than 1, it is a counting semaphore and it can be used for problems like the consumer-producer problem where you want manage multiple instances of a resource across different consumers of that resource. To understand how the initial value affects synchronization, you have to understand what happens when you wait or signal on a semaphore.

### Wait

1. Decrease value of the semaphore (represented by initial_value) by 1.
2. Check if the value is smaller than 0.
3. If the value is smaller than 0, put the process to sleep and place it in the semaphore queue. The CPU no longer tries to schedule this process and this results in performance improvement compared to the more naive busy wait approach.
4. If the value is greater or equal to 0, the process is not blocked and it continues its execution.

### Signal

1. Increment the value of the semaphore.
2. If the value of the semaphore is smaller or equal to 0, then it means a certain process previously called a wait on the semaphore and is still blocked on it. In that case, we are signalling this process, informing it that it can now resume its execution. We take the first process in the semaphore queue out for it to resume its execution. The CPU is responsible for scheduling it to run again.

This said, if you want to ensure mutual exclusion, you simply set initial_value to 1.

To wait on your semaphore, call:

```
sem_wait(&name_of_your_semaphore);
```

This will result in the process described above, value is decremented. If it's zero, the process is the first one to call wait so it does not have to wait (it would be the first one trying to access the resource you are trying to secure). If the value is smaller than 0, the process is put to sleep and placed in the semaphore queue.

To signal your semaphore (ie, tell a process that was waiting in the queue that it can resume its execution):

```
sem_post(&name_of_your_semaphore);
```

Results in the process described above.

Hope this helps.